# Identity Not Working if adding "IdentitiesOnly yes" to *

Tags: ssh

I have a config file in .ssh here

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
IdentitiesOnly yes

#Github (default)
Host gh
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#Bitbucket (secondary)
Host bb
HostName bitbucket.org
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bb

#Azure DevOps (secondary)
Host ado
HostName ssh.dev.azure.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ado
IdentitiesOnly yes

#GitLab
Host gitlab.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gl
```

If I have `IdentitiesOnly yes` set in the * host, I cannot SSH to bitbucket, but all of the other connections work:

```
% ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Removing the IdentitiesOnly config causes the bitbucket ssh to work. I've tried reloading the identity as well with

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would suggest the public key configured in the `authorized_keys` file (or equivalent) for `git@bitbucket.org` might not actually be the one corresponding the private key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa_bb`, but one of the other keys available in the agent.

Try `ssh -v -T git@bitbucket.org` with `IdentitiesOnly` set to `no`, and read the debug messages to see which key is actually accepted by the remote host.

Comment: thanks! known_hosts had the wrong key listed.